# How can I bridge br0 to wlp2s0 so virtual machines get a dynamic IP from router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, linux-kvm

For static ethernet interfaces (`eno1`), I use the following (`cat /etc/network/interfaces`):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp

# The bridge network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 10.0.1.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.1.0
  broadcast 10.0.1.255
  gateway 10.0.1.1
  bridge_ports eno1
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0
  dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

What is the equivalent for DHCP wireless interfaces (`wlp2s0`, no cable plugged into `eno1`)? This is how I connect so far without the bridge (`cat /etc/network/interfaces`):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

# The wireless network interfac
allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out its not possible to bridge over a wireless interface so I ended up using a NAT-based network.

See https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/nat-based-network.html